# Letterspacing in lualatex doesn't work properly with Warnock Pro

Tags: fonts, luatex, polyglossia, letterspacing

Consider the following example set in Warnock Pro with lualatex:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{russian}
\setmainfont{Warnock Pro}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
lualatex:

\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}
активный словарь русского языка

АКТИВНЫЙ СЛОВАРЬ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА
\end{document}
```

Capitals are not spaced properly (see the screenshot).  Without `\setmainlanguage{russian}` or when typeset with xelatex, they are. Is it a problem of the font itself or some bug?

[image: with lualatex]

*Update*: `[Renderer=Node]` solves the problem, kudos to Javier Bezos

Comment: Where does not get that font? It is not in TL23 it seems

Comment: I've got it some time ago in a bundle with other Adobe fonts, it is not free, AFAIK

Comment: I’ve tested it with with `babel` and it worked as expected. So the problem is the renderer — by default `Node` with `babel` but `Harfbuzz` with `polyglossia`. If you are using LGR scripts, `Node` is usually a better option, so use `\setmainfont[Renderer=Node]{Warnock Pro}`.

Comment: Oops! I meant LGC (Latin-Greek-Cyrillic).

Comment: Thank you, Javier! your approach works with `polyglossia` too. I wonder how many not-so-evident inaccuracies `Harfbuzz` has -- when I recompiled the whole volume of the dictionary with `[Renderer=Node]` there were 2 hundred lines of diff with the previous version

Comment: @VadimRadionov Very likely because now it’s correctly hyphenated. Sadly, there is a bug in the `Harfbuzz` renderer and (depending on the font) many hyphenation points are dropped (and this is the very reason `babel` sticks to the default renderer, ie, `Node`). For further info see https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/wiki/Comparing-the-modes.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to the `Node` renderer suggested by @JavierBezos solves this issue (and probably some others):

```
\setmainfont[Renderer=Node]{Warnock Pro}
```